# why is activerecord not finding records with null columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So, if I do:

```
>> User.where("facebook_data IS null")
(0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE (facebook_data IS null)
=> []
```

If yet, I look up my user account:

```
>> u = User.find(225)
=> #<User id: 225, email: "me@example.com", ...etc>
>> u.facebook_data
=> nil
```

So I clearly have no `facebook_data`. Why is this record not coming up when I use the where clause?

Comment: Have you tried `User.where(:facebook_data => nil)`?

Comment: yes, I get the same result-- and I need to be able to get the reverse, hence why I am doing IS null, I also need to do IS NOT null...  So, if I do this:  User.where("facebook_data IS NOT null").map { |u| u if u.facebook_data.nil? }.compact  --- Then I get my user!!!  So.. seriously something is totally broken here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so getting to the bottom of this, I went into mysql:

```
mysql> select users.facebook_data from users WHERE users.id = 225;
+---------------+
| facebook_data |
+---------------+
| --- 
         |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And then in the console..

```
> User.find(225).facebook_data == nil
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 225 LIMIT 1
=> true
```

So...  ActiveRecord has somehow put "---" in the column instead of "NULL"......  And ActiveRecord recognizes "---" as null, but mysql disagrees.

Comment: I'd suspect that you're serializing your `facebook_data` column :)